# '06 Charger Broken Glove Box Latch

Tags: dodge, locks, charger

So my brother borrowed my car, and tried to open my glove box in my 2006 Dodge Charger SXT. The glove box was locked, and he tried to force it open thinking it was jammed. I unlocked it later but he had already broken the latch. Now I need to get into the glove box to get to my registration and GPS. I can't figure out how to get it open. I've added some pictures below to show what I'm dealing with. No screws on the glove box, no tabs or screws under it, nothing obvious under (or inside) the latch for me to pick. I think the things under the latch are what I need to be working with. There was a spring in there that I tried pushing but I popped it halfway out, so it seems I should get some advise before I continue poking around.

Entire glove box:

[image]

Under the glove box latch:

[image]

Area under the glove box where it connects to the fabric:

[image: Area under the glove box where it connects to the fabric]

Answer (score 3):

Although I haven't done one of these in particular (but a *bunch* of the little pink shift interlock levers; **darn Mopar**), here is my suggestion:

Your glovebox latch assembly is broken.  Busticated.  *You are going to have to buy a new one.*   (Or better yet, "Let me know *Monday morning* when you've bought my new latch, Brother...")   Not to worry -- less than $40 everywhere I looked.

Once you have the new assembly (And I believe it comes as a unit, but requires an interior color to determine the part number to match your dashboard) you can operate the unit out of the car to visually determine exactly how it works.

And more importantly, armed with your new knowledge, where exactly to put the screwdriver/prybar/sledgehammer/Hurst rescue tool to subtly and gradual fluffy kittens gently pry the old glovebox latch open (but accept NO backtalk), so as not to break any part of the *glovebox door*, which is $200 compared to the $32 latch.  Please no of do any *that*.

Once open, this view will allow you to reach the mounting screws and install the new latch assembly.  You may need to transfer over the lock cylinder.

Yes, some eggs will get broken for this omlette.  But those eggs were already broken.  I sincerely doubt there is a clean way to "repair" this in place.

After all, if there were, it would defeat the purpose of the glove box lock in the first place.

Here's a '06 parts diagram I done founded on the interwebs.  I don't know if your "beige" is actually "Royal Bright Early Morning Desert Sand", but with some work you can find your trim codes and order (I suggest online, and your brother to do the heavy lifting)...

[image]